# Corrupted or broken favicons in Google Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, favicon

The other day I noticed some of my bookmarks in Google Chrome looked a bit off, the icons in my toolbar were seemingly corrupted. It seems this only affects certain websites, Outlook and Facebook's favicons look like they should, while Reddit, StackOverflow and Youtube's favicons are mangled.

To fix it, I thought, I went ahead and cleared all my caches, and deleted `Favicons` and `Favicons-journal` files under `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`. But the issue remained the same.

I have tried opening up Chrome DevTools and performing a "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" as illustrated here:

[image: Performing Empty Cache and Hard Reload in Google Chrome on Youtube.com]

But as you can see the issue persists.

The issue seems to be with Chromium based browsers on my computer, Microsoft Edge displays the same mangled favicons

[image: Youtube.com in Microsoft Edge]

Whilst Firefox is unaffected.

[image: Youtube.com in Mozilla Firefox]

Comment: Weird. Can you check if disabling hardware acceleration changes the behaviour? Can you see if updating Chrome/Edge resolves the issue?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I tried turning off hardware acceleration, my jaw dropped; it worked! The icons for the websites in question are back to normal. But now I'm a bit confused, why did that work, and will I ever be able to use hardware acceleration again?

Comment: I don't know the why... Perhaps a driver issue as your machine is somewhat older?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue seems to be with Google Chrome itself. I have gotten in touch with support and we are trying to figure it out.

Follow the Google Chrome Help thread [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/197846594)

**Update:** NVIDIA Customer Support knows about the case and have forwarded it to their Engineering Department. This post will be updated.

NVIDIA Customer Support has updated the case and found that this does not affect only NVIDIA customers, but AMD and Intel as well. The main issue seems to be with Google Chrome and the only temporary fix is to disable Hardware Acceleration.

**Final update:** As of Google Chrome version 111.0.5563.65 the issue seems to be fixed.